# Pymongo echoes 'killed' and terminates query on a medium-scale query

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pymongo

I am trying to run a query that is supposed to select several fields out of a mongodb collection (arround 20,000 objects with an average size of ~ 20k each).
In the middle of the query run, I get a 'Killed' message outputed to the console, and the script dies.

The hardware is Amazon AWS EC2 m3.medium, running ubuntu 12.04

**db stats:**

```
{
    "ns" : "vita.raw_data",
    "count" : 95976,
    "size" : 21912264248,
    "avgObjSize" : 228309.83004084355,
    "storageSize" : 25440595872,
    "numExtents" : 40,
    "nindexes" : 4,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1.0099999999997797,
    "flags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 12059600,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 3204992,
        "index_1_last_response_1" : 2330160,
        "retailer_id_1" : 3899952,
        "retailer_id_1_category_leaf_1_category_set_1" : 2624496
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

**/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log**

```
  Thu May  8 14:13:48 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48590 #5
    Thu May  8 14:13:48 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:59 reslen:4221591 173ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:49 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:59 reslen:4242110 162ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:49 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:59 reslen:4235627 167ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:49 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:59 reslen:4217085 174ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:49 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:60 reslen:4247976 156ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:50 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:59 reslen:4238294 175ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:50 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:59 reslen:4222222 170ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:50 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:58 reslen:4194810 183ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:50 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:60 reslen:4232253 154ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:50 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:59 reslen:4204341 164ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:51 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:59 reslen:4222782 162ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:51 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:60 reslen:4226366 160ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:51 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:60 reslen:4226044 160ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:51 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:60 reslen:4236671 159ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:52 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:60 reslen:4250988 185ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:52 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:60 reslen:4239619 411ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:53 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:61 reslen:4253878 670ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:53 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:60 reslen:4197101 162ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:53 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:60 reslen:4220863 241ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:54 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:59 reslen:4223308 239ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:55 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:56 reslen:4215477 192ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:56 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:56 reslen:4226147 238ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:57 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:56 reslen:4230631 246ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:58 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:56 reslen:4205313 248ms
    Thu May  8 14:13:59 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:56 reslen:4236395 238ms
    Thu May  8 14:14:00 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:55 reslen:4216751 259ms
    Thu May  8 14:14:01 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:57 reslen:4213662 239ms
    Thu May  8 14:14:01 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:57 reslen:4234624 131ms
    Thu May  8 14:14:02 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:57 reslen:4211163 128ms
    Thu May  8 14:14:03 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:58 reslen:4221606 255ms
    Thu May  8 14:14:05 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:59 reslen:4250148 104ms
    Thu May  8 14:14:05 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:59 reslen:4219099 267ms
    Thu May  8 14:14:07 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:61 reslen:4199884 267ms
    Thu May  8 14:14:08 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:58 reslen:4208595 242ms
    Thu May  8 14:14:09 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:60 reslen:4220319 262ms
    Thu May  8 14:14:11 [conn5] getmore vita.raw_data query: { retailer_id: 2 } cursorid:8677435513443899340 nreturned:60 reslen:4248640 334ms
    Thu May  8 14:14:17 [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:48590
```

**/var/log/syslog**

```
May  8 14:14:01 staging-api CRON[10987]: (root) CMD (/etc/ganglia/scripts/diskstats-xvdap1 > /dev/null 2>&1)
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149946] nginx invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149952] nginx cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149955] Pid: 964, comm: nginx Not tainted 3.2.0-60-virtual #91-Ubuntu
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149957] Call Trace:
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149964]  [<ffffffff8111b481>] dump_header+0x91/0xe0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149966]  [<ffffffff8111b805>] oom_kill_process+0x85/0xb0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149968]  [<ffffffff8111bbaa>] out_of_memory+0xfa/0x220
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149971]  [<ffffffff81121583>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8c3/0x8e0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149976]  [<ffffffff81158746>] alloc_pages_current+0xb6/0x120
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149979]  [<ffffffff811183a7>] __page_cache_alloc+0xb7/0xd0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149981]  [<ffffffff8111a372>] filemap_fault+0x212/0x3c0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149984]  [<ffffffff8113aab2>] __do_fault+0x72/0x550
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149988]  [<ffffffff81013728>] ? __switch_to+0x138/0x360
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149990]  [<ffffffff8113e16a>] handle_pte_fault+0xfa/0x200
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149993]  [<ffffffff810063fe>] ? xen_pmd_val+0xe/0x10
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149995]  [<ffffffff81005379>] ? __raw_callee_save_xen_pmd_val+0x11/0x1e
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.149998]  [<ffffffff8113f449>] handle_mm_fault+0x269/0x370
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150002]  [<ffffffff8165f584>] do_page_fault+0x184/0x550
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150005]  [<ffffffff8165ba6e>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x1e/0x30
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150009]  [<ffffffff811bcf9c>] ? ep_poll+0x1cc/0x380
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150013]  [<ffffffff810607c0>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x200/0x200
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150016]  [<ffffffff8165c1b5>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150017] Mem-Info:
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150018] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150020] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150022] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150023] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150026] active_anon:922299 inactive_anon:47 isolated_anon:0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150026]  active_file:33 inactive_file:89 isolated_file:0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150027]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150028]  free:4048 slab_reclaimable:1994 slab_unreclaimable:2086
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150028]  mapped:28 shmem:56 pagetables:16092 bounce:0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150030] Node 0 DMA free:8336kB min:16kB low:20kB high:24kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:8080kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150036] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3772 3772 3772
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150039] Node 0 DMA32 free:7856kB min:7848kB low:9808kB high:11772kB active_anon:3689196kB inactive_anon:188kB active_file:132kB inactive_file:356kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3862656kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:112kB shmem:224kB slab_reclaimable:7976kB slab_unreclaimable:8344kB kernel_stack:856kB pagetables:64368kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:87851 all_unreclaimable? yes
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150045] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150048] Node 0 DMA: 2*4kB 3*8kB 1*16kB 1*32kB 3*64kB 3*128kB 2*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 1*2048kB 1*4096kB = 8336kB
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150055] Node 0 DMA32: 838*4kB 5*8kB 21*16kB 1*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 7856kB
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150062] 191 total pagecache pages
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150063] 0 pages in swap cache
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150064] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150065] Free swap  = 0kB
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.150066] Total swap = 0kB
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155922] 985072 pages RAM
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155925] 24961 pages reserved
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155925] 6551 pages shared
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155926] 954054 pages non-shared
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155928] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss cpu oom_adj oom_score_adj name
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155935] [  198]     0   198     6326       84   0       0             0 mountall
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155938] [  284]     0   284     4309       49   0       0             0 upstart-udev-br
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155940] [  371]     0   371     5381      133   0     -17         -1000 udevd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155942] [  435]     0   435     5367      102   0     -17         -1000 udevd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155944] [  436]     0   436     5367      102   0     -17         -1000 udevd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155947] [  520]     0   520     4801       71   0       0             0 rpcbind
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155949] [  546]     0   546     3798       52   0       0             0 upstart-socket-
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155951] [  583]     0   583     1817      124   0       0             0 dhclient3
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155953] [  752]   104   752     9444      158   0       0             0 ntpd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155955] [  793]     0   793    12510      151   0     -17         -1000 sshd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155958] [  802]   106   802     5377      115   0       0             0 rpc.statd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155960] [  807]   101   807    62369      130   0       0             0 rsyslogd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155962] [  818]   102   818     5955       73   0       0             0 dbus-daemon
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155964] [  874]     0   874     3627       42   0       0             0 getty
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155966] [  878]     0   878     6386       56   0       0             0 rpc.idmapd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155968] [  879]     0   879     3627       42   0       0             0 getty
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155970] [  891]     0   891     3627       43   0       0             0 getty
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155972] [  893]     0   893     3627       42   0       0             0 getty
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155974] [  895]     0   895     3627       41   0       0             0 getty
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155976] [  920]   108   920 16916403     5645   0       0             0 mongod
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155978] [  921]     0   921     1083       36   0       0             0 acpid
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155980] [  922]     0   922     4779       53   0       0             0 cron
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155982] [  924]     0   924     4228       40   0       0             0 atd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155984] [  931]     0   931    76570      110   0       0             0 automount
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155986] [  943]   103   943    46919      320   0       0             0 whoopsie
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155989] [  945]   998   945    18965     1747   0       0             0 gmond
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155991] [  957]     0   957    15719      261   0       0             0 nginx
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155993] [  959]    33   959    15840      360   0       0             0 nginx
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155995] [  960]    33   960    15840      360   0       0             0 nginx
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155997] [  961]    33   961    15840      360   0       0             0 nginx
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.155998] [  962]    33   962    15840      360   0       0             0 nginx
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156000] [  963]    33   963    15840      360   0       0             0 nginx
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156002] [  964]    33   964    15840      360   0       0             0 nginx
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156004] [  965]    33   965    15840      360   0       0             0 nginx
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156006] [  966]    33   966    15840      360   0       0             0 nginx
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156008] [  967]    33   967    15840      360   0       0             0 nginx
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156010] [  968]    33   968    15840      360   0       0             0 nginx
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156013] [  972]   109   972     5505      149   0       0             0 privoxy
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156015] [ 1034]     0  1034    26056      145   0       0             0 monit
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156017] [ 1059]     0  1059     3627       40   0       0             0 getty
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156019] [ 1062]   999  1062    35145    12734   0       0             0 opsworks-agent
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156022] [ 1064]   999  1064    43541    17536   0       0             0 opsworks-agent
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156024] [ 1071]   999  1071    43659    17625   0       0             0 opsworks-agent
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156026] [ 1077]   999  1077    42805    16782   0       0             0 opsworks-agent
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156028] [ 1238]     0  1238    18361      201   0       0             0 sshd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156030] [ 1365]  2003  1365    18361      200   0       0             0 sshd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156032] [ 1366]  2003  1366     6513     1719   0       0             0 bash
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156035] [ 7725]     0  7725    18361      200   0       0             0 sshd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156037] [ 7893]  2003  7893    18361      199   0       0             0 sshd
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156039] [ 7894]  2003  7894     6580     1784   0       0             0 bash
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156041] [10972]  2003 10972     1480       24   0       0             0 tail
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156044] [10977]  2003 10977   879279   845692   0       0             0 python
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156046] Out of memory: Kill process 10977 (python) score 882 or sacrifice child
May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156056] Killed process 10977 (python) total-vm:3517116kB, anon-rss:3382768kB, file-rss:
```

[kern.log](https://code.stypi.com/dmnabc6j)

Comment: Can you check /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log and check for oom-killer, oom, Out of memory or similar strings? Also, can you run this and in another terminal window run mongostat and copy the output from just before and just after the process dies into the question?

Comment: Posted, doesn't look suspicious to me, but what do I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running out of memory and the Linux OOM killer is selecting processes to kill and free up memory.

> May  8 14:14:17 staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156046] Out of memory: Kill
>   process 10977 (python) score 882 or sacrifice child May  8 14:14:17
>   staging-api kernel: [ 8058.156056] Killed process 10977 (python)
>   total-vm:3517116kB, anon-rss:3382768kB, file-rss:

When Linux runs critically low on memory it may invoke the OOM killer to kill a process to free up memory. From what I can see you are running mongodb, nginx and your python script all on a EC2 medium instance with around 20GB of data in the database. That's probably a bit tight - I'd look at a few options:

1. Upgrade to a larger instance type with more memory
2. Move you python code and nginx web site off to another instance
3. Try tuning your python code - looks to be eating up a fair amount of memory
4. Try tuning the OOM killer to be less strict - not for the faint of heart, but here are a few articles if you are interested:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58872/how-to-set-oom-killer-adjustments-for-daemons-permanently

http://backdrift.org/how-to-create-oom-killer-exceptions

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html

Comment: Thanks man, was able to hack it out by separating the queries to smaller batches :P

Amazon nodes are very pricey, we'll probably move to Linode at the first opportunity